# How do I take the logarithm of a long in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to take the logarithm of a very large number (`long` type).

```
from scipy import misc
from numpy import log

n1 = 40000
k1 = 20000
r = log(misc.comb(n1, k1, exact=True))
```

throws

> AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'log'

and if I try to convert to a `float`:

> *** OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float

Knowing the number of digits would be appropriate as well. I noticed that `long` has a `bit_length()` builtin, but I'm not sure how that translates into the number of digits. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you convert it to float?

Comment: Too big to convert. I'll put that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `math.log` instead of `numpy.log`.

```
from scipy import misc
import math

n1 = 40000
k1 = 20000
r = math.log(misc.comb(n1, k1, exact=True),10)
```

It should give `12038.800733910726` that you can round.

Comment: well! for natural log, 10 is not requisite.

Comment: @B.M., you are right! I added the base 10 because the OP asks for the number of digit. Since it is an optional parameter, the OP will decide to keep or remove it, or even add another basis that is suited to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

`n=misc.comb(n1, k1, exact=True)` is a very big number, so can't be converted to float. `len(str(n))` give the number of decimal digits : 12039.

You can also find the number of digits by `r.bit_length()/log2(10)=12039.09`